# Can I exclude volumes from vMotion in ESX?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

When I do vmotion, the VM's vmdk is usually on a shared storage array (unless I use storage, etc., but let's assume this is enterprise with a SAN).

What if I have 2 volumes: one is the VMDK for the VM, the other is a separately mounted volume for prodigious logs. I might use a local disk.

I am far more tolerant of losing logs in the event of a failure than the VM itself, and the logs demand significant write IO; I prefer to keep that local rather than slam the storage array.

Can I do a vmotion move *without* moving the logfile disk over?

Or will it file because of open file descriptions in memory, etc.?

Yes, I know, logs should be sent to a log collector and not on disk, but that will take some time to set up; splitting my critical volume (VM) from less-critical (logs) can provide an interim solution.

Comment: What versions, builds and tier of VMware vSphere are you using?

Comment: Mix of ESXi 5.0 and 5.1. Need more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to clarify :

`vMotion` : will move your VM to another ESXi server, leaving VM storage on its original Datastore.

`Storage vMotion` : will move VM storage to another Datastore, leaving the VM on its original ESXi server.

**Edit :**

Using Storage vMotion advanced settings, you can specify which storage you want to move and where, and also choose to leave some of the storage in its current location :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @KrisFR, that does clarify. Basically, I have to move all of the storage, or have it on shared storage.

Comment: So local swap file/volume is treated specially?

Comment: @krisFR That's wrong. You can svMotion a VM and one of its disks and leave another disk where it is or even svMotion it to a different destination.

Comment: @Mario Lenz You are right. I wanted to delete my answer but i cannot because it is accepted, so i've edited it. Thank you

Comment: @deitch Please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Using Storage vMotion, you can relocate a VM with disk-level granularity. However, moving a VM from one host to another with a dependency on a local VMDK (on one host) won't work.

[image]

Comment: I did not understand. Does that mean we can, or we cannot? "dependency on a local VMDK" i.e. if there is a local log disk it won't work? Or "disk-level granularity" means it will work?

Comment: vMotion and Storage vMotion (relocation) are slightly different.

Comment: @ewwhite It looks like you *can* vMotion a VM with a dependency on a local VMDK to another host if you svMotion said VMDK (to shared storage or storage that's local to the destination host) at the same time: http://www.vladan.fr/vmware-enhanced-vmotion/ Havn't done this myself yet, though...

Answer (score 0):

This sound rather like an HA question. In VMware you would have to set up a cluster between two VMs and switch the service with a fail over cluster.